# Campaigns and Person Accounts - Rollup

Tags: administration, account, person-accounts, roll-up-summary, campaign

I have searched Google;  searched AppExchange;  asked the two people in my office who would remotely have a clue - no go.

We need to basically create **ROLLUP SUMMARY FIELDS on the Campaign object**... rolling up information **from the Account object** (we use PERSON ACCOUNTS - yay).  The data is specifically on the Account (not the Contact).   The data actually resides on the OPPORTUNITY, but we "piggyback" Opp data to the Account already, so at least the "up-over-down" situation does not exist, just "up" to the Account itself.

**Simple example would be**:  Rollup a COUNT of those Accounts (in the Campaign) which have "PB_XYZ__c" = "Closed Won"

I note that for certain filtering needs you DO GET the Account fields available, but when trying to do a ROLLUP field on the Campaign, the attached screenshot is all you get.

[image]

Help?   Any bright ideas outside of fancy Apex programming?   :-/  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itmanhah's suggestion should work. Give it a try.

just for a bit of info...

Rollup Summary fields only work to roll up information from child records onto the parent in a master-detail relationship. Campaigns and Accounts are not directly associated in this way. For instance, Accounts do not belong to campaigns. Neither do contacts. They may be associated by way of contacts, but the system will not give you access to those fields through a rollup field.

Part of it has to do with the fact that campaigns may have both contacts and leads associated with it, but they are added as "campaign members", which is a separate object as well and moves with the person from lead to contact so that you don't lose that history. So you really don't have contacts or leads directly associated in a data relationship that works as you want.

I would review this help page just so you understand it a bit more.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm

Comment: I'm discovering that this is true - Campaigns have the same "bastard child" (or parent as the case may be) relationship to other records as my old nemesis, Task.  (sigh)   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think campaign members is a separate object providing a many to many relationship between accounts and campaigns...

If I'm correct in this then you would need to add a custom formula field to the campaign member object "piggy backing" data from the account and then roll that up to the campaign.